# Any way to make UNION ALL run faster?

Tags: mysql

I have a lot of exactly same tables. TableA,TableB,TableC,TableD etc. which I want to create views from. 
Doing `select * from TableA` takes 20ms, doing `select * from tableB` takes 20ms, but doing
`(select * from TableA) union all (select * from TableB)` takes over 20 minutes.
Those tables have exactly same columns. Is there any settings in my.cnf that I need to change, or a way to create a view that would run faster? All tables have 1.5m to about 10m rows.

Results of explain

```
PRIMARY TableA  ALL                 28808685    
UNION   TableB  ALL                 15316215    
UNION RESULT    <union1,2>  ALL     Using temporary
```

Table structure:
10 varchar(20)'s, 5 unsigned INTs.

Comment: `DESCRIBE` and `EXPLAIN`, please.

Comment: If your Table A has 1.5 million rows, it can not take only 20ms to return all those rows. If you are returning anywhere from 5M to 40M rows, it is going to take *a lot* of time - there might be other things you can optimize, such as the method of retreiving data (using a cursor, vs returning everything in memory etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `select * from TableA` does not take 20 ms.  It takes 20 ms to start returning results.

Although I am going to answer your question, you should revisit your data structure.  Having multiple tables with the same layout is usually a really bad idea.  Instead, you should have a single table with all the rows.

But, you don't seem to have that.

Try running the `union all` without parentheses:

```
select * from TableA union all
select * from TableB;
```

MySQL has a habit of materializing subqueries.  I'm not sure if it does this with `union all` subqueries, but given your description of the problem, that sees likely.

Comment: if I have a single table with all rows, i will have 250+m rows and growing. The difference between tableA's and tableB's  data is that tableA has data only for clientA and tableB has data only for clientB. The proprietary tool that data feeds into does select * from table and then processes data and throws away useless one. If we point it to the one massive table, it will time-out/run out of memory and do all kinds of silly things.

Comment: Figured out the issue. It was the time to first byte (or the equivalency of it in mysql) which caused connection timeout. Union ALL was first generating that table on server, then sending it. Thank you.